# NG3003: Trying to publish a package that has been compiled by Ivy in full compilation mode. This is not allowed

Tags: angular, circular-dependency, ivy, compilationmode

It seems that it is no more possible to publish libraries compiled in full ivy compilation mode. I have many cyclic components in my project for recursive reasons.
Is there a way to ignore this check through a setting ?

Comment: Why would you want to compile in full compilation mode in the first place ?

Comment: We have components with cyclic dependencies in our project and this is no more allowed in partial compilation mode. Since I am not the owner of the related components, I have to wait for a fix and meantime find a way to proceed.